# How to close popup windows in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm doing a test with java and popup windows appear (ads) and I do not know how to close them to continue with my test. 
I have to click on a button but I change the focus to the window.
The url is www.orbitz.com
Please help!

[orbitz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WFnC.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Java solution:

```
//switch to opened tab
ArrayList<String> tabs_windows = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs_windows.get(1));
//close current tab and switch driver back to original
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("close();");
for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
driver.switchTo().window(winHandle); 
 }
```

I haven't tested this for a while, but in different browsers getWindowHandles() used to return different orders for the tabs.  Not sure if you can assume 0 is the first tab for all browsers.  Change the index accordingly, or store the current handle before popup, and close all that don't match that.